# Reflection issue upgrading .net 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.5

I am working on migrating our .net application from >net version 3.5 to 4.5 .
I just started the work by changing the target runtime in visual studio for the project to 4.5.
My development machine has >net 4.6 installed.

Now i have code that looks like this,

```
    Dim privateConstructors As System.Reflection.BindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
    Dim safeRegistryHandleType As System.Type = GetType(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle")
    Dim safeRegistryHandleConstructorTypes As System.Type() = {GetType(System.IntPtr), GetType(System.Boolean)}
    Dim safeRegistryHandleConstructor As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo = safeRegistryHandleType.GetConstructor(privateConstructors, Nothing, safeRegistryHandleConstructorTypes, Nothing)
    Dim safeHandle As System.Object = safeRegistryHandleConstructor.Invoke(New System.Object() {hKey, ownsHandle})

    Dim registryKeyType As System.Type = GetType(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey)
    Dim registryKeyConstructorTypes As System.Type() = {safeRegistryHandleType, GetType(System.Boolean)}
    Dim registryKeyConstructor As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo = registryKeyType.GetConstructor(privateConstructors, Nothing, registryKeyConstructorTypes, Nothing)
    Dim result As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = DirectCast(registryKeyConstructor.Invoke(New Object() {safeHandle, writable}), Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey)
```

Now this works fine when the code runs with .net 3.5.
The moment i run it with .net 4.5 it gives a exception(nullpointer)
This is because the `safeRegistryHandleConstructor` variable is set to nothing at the end of the second last line.
I fail to understand why would this happen. 
No API that i am seeing has been used has changed at all between 3.5 and 4.5 !

Please advise. I am new to .net.

Edit:

At a higher level i am trying to do this,

```
Dim regkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Nothing
regkey = OpenSubKey(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine, AppConstant.REGISTRY_PATH, False, RegWow64Options.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

After this i will get the individual entries from the `regkey`.
Can you suggest some other way than reflection to get the key ?

Edit 2:

After changing `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to `BindingFlags.Public` the execution error is gone but the same error occurs after the last line. It says that the `registryKeyConstructor` is set to nothing and reports an error.

Comment: That is why you don't use reflection. Sure, you may think you need to call a private constructor, but it's private for a reason. It can change with any framework update and isn't documented. The [`SafeRegistryHandle(IntPtr, bool)` constructor is public anyway](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.saferegistryhandle.saferegistryhandle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please see the edit. Can you please explain how should i proceed.

Comment: It is a public constructor, so you need `BindingFlags.Public`.

Comment: I did that and the error is resolved. Now i see the same error after 4 more lines of code. These lines are updated in the main question

Comment: let me know if you are online ? Need help. :)